# if condition is not working when using $.post()

Tags: jquery, asp.net, authentication

I have one image button with OnClientClick and OnClick events.

```
        <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="./../../images/login.gif" Style="margin-right: 153px;"
        runat="server" OnClientClick="return SendLoginData();" OnClick="Login_Click" />
```

OnClientClick, I call some client side function SendLoginData() where I used $.post() function.

```
    function SendLoginData() {
        var flagLogin = "0";
        if (LoginValidation() != false) {
            $.post(window.location,
                {
                    LOGIN: "LOGIN",
                    UserName: $.trim($('#txtUserNameLogin').val()),
                    Password: $.trim($('#txtPasswordLogin').val())
                },
                function (data) {

                    var d = $(data).find('#<%=lblMessageLogin.ClientID %>');
                    if ($(d).html() == "SUCCESS") {
                        flagLogin = "1";
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#lblErrorMsgLogin').html(d.html());
                    }
                }
            );
        }
        //alert(flagLogin);
        if (flagLogin == "1") {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Afer $.post() When I get response as "SUCCESS", I want to return true to client side function SendLoginData.
So that my server side onClick can work.

But I am facing one problem.
You can see there is one alert which is commented ( //alert(flagLogin);).

if I uncomment the alert then  if (flagLogin == "1") condition works. whereas if I left alert as commented then  if (flagLogin == "1") doesn't work.

Can someone explain how can I handle this situation and what is the reason behind this?

Comment: The code after `$.post` is executed before the code in the `$.post` callback. Consider reading tutorials on AJAX.

Comment: big security concerns also, see my answer (last edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this kind of scenario by using below code

```
    function SendLoginData() {
        var flagLogin = "0";
        if (LoginValidation() != false) {

            $.post(window.location,
                {
                    LOGIN: "LOGIN",
                    UserName: $.trim($('#txtUserNameLogin').val()),
                    Password: $.trim($('#txtPasswordLogin').val())
                },
                function (data) {

                    var d = $(data).find('#<%=lblMessageLogin.ClientID %>');
                    if ($(d).html() == "SUCCESS") {
                        flagLogin = "1";
                        window.location = window.location + "?HOME=true";
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#lblErrorMsgLogin').html(d.html());
                    }
                }
            );

        }
        if (flagLogin == "1") {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Here, I used window.location with some querystring in callback function to execute my server side code and it is working fine.

Answer (score 4):

Because the request is asynchronous. An AJAX call doesn't "wait" the request to complete, so your "if" is executed BEFORE the request completes.

In other words, the code continues it's execution flow, while the POST request is handled, and your flag gets valued when the `SendLoginData()` function has already finished.

You should manage login success in the `function (data)` bit inside the POST request.

---

By the way: DON'T EVER rely on JavaScript to validate a login, it can be tampered with with **extreme** ease. Consider a radical approach change.

Comment: Another addition: the scope of the flag dies within the function, so when the $.post success function is executed, it's refering to another, unrelated, variable.

Comment: Also, I think scope of the flag doesn't die because after uncommenting alert, I am able to see the value to 1

Comment: @Gaurav You are able to see the value, but from a variable with the same name. As for the first question, it's a login and should *not ever* be done with a JavaScript flag it's a massive security hole.
Anyway for scenarios like these: you can not expect *callback functions* (like the one in your $.post) to *return* a value.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestions.